# Python. Clasificar colores en cálidos, neutros y fríos

Tags: python

Quiero clasificar colores en cálido, frío o neutro en Python según el código RGB.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Lo que pides no tiene relación con Python, C++, Javascript ni ningún otro lenguaje de programación. De todas maneras, revisa esta pregunta: [RGB range for cold and warm colors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615029/rgb-range-for-cold-and-warm-colors#4615364)

Comment: En resumen: un color es cálido si su componente Rojo es mayor que componente Azul. Un color es frio si el componente Azul es mayor que el Rojo.

Comment: Muy buen resumen de mi respuesta. Gracias.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

El que un color sea cálido o frío depende de su "matiz" (*hue* en inglés). La rueda de matices tiene típicamente este aspecto:

[image: Rueda de matices, de Wikipedia]

El valor H (*hue*) es una medida en grados, siendo 0 el norte (rojo), y avanzando en el sentido de las agujas de reloj, por lo que el amarillo sería más o menos 60º, el verde puro estaría en 120º, en 180º está el cyan, etc.

Podríamos tratar de dividir el círculo de *hue* en dos mitades, de modo que a un lado queden los colores cálidos y al contrario los fríos. Esto puede ser un poco subjetivo pero yo diría que la franja que va desde -45 grados hasta 135 aproximadamente serviría para esa clasificación. Dejaría colores obviamente cálidos como rojo, naranja, magenta, a un lado, y colores obviamente fríos como cyan, azul al otro. El verde es un poco discutible, pues quedaría partido en "verdes cálidos" y "verdes fríos".

Pero si prescindimos de detalles en la frontera, yo veo esto como una aproximación suficientemente buena.

No obstante el matiz (*hue*) no es el único parámetro que define un color. Una vez elegido un matiz como el rojo, hay toda una variedad de rojos que van desde el más saturado (rojo puro) al blanco, pasando por una gama de rosas, y también al negro a medida que se oscurece.

Un color neutro sería aquel que tiene baja saturación (y por tanto "tira al gris"), con independencia de su *hue*. También, si tiene brillo muy bajo, se verá casi negro por lo que su calidez o frialdad será difícil de percibir y lo veremos como neutro.

Por tanto podemos escribir un código que convierta RGB en HSV y después use H, S y V para clasificar el color como cálido, frío o neutro:

```
def hex_to_rgb(rgb):
  "Separa cadena tipo '#ff00f4' en tres enteros (255, 0, 254)"
  if rgb.startswith("#"):
    rgb = rgb[1:]       # Eliminar el # inicial
  return int(rgb[:2], 16), int(rgb[2:4], 16), int(rgb[4:6], 16)


def rgb_to_hsv(hex_rgb):
    """Recibe cadena hex tipo '#ff00fe' y devuelve su valor de hue,
    saturación y valor"""

    r, g, b = hex_to_rgb(hex_rgb)
    r, g, b = r/255.0, g/255.0, b/255.0
    mx = max(r, g, b)
    mn = min(r, g, b)
    df = mx-mn
    if mx == mn:
        h = 0
    elif mx == r:
        h = (60 * ((g-b)/df) + 360) % 360
    elif mx == g:
        h = (60 * ((b-r)/df) + 120) % 360
    elif mx == b:
        h = (60 * ((r-g)/df) + 240) % 360
    if mx == 0:
        s = 0
    else:
        s = df/mx
    v = mx
    return h, s, v

def calidez(color, limite=135, rango=180, neutro=0.4):
  """Recibe cadena hex tipo '#ff00fe' y lo clasifica como Calido,
  Frio o Neutro"""

  h, s, v = rgb_to_hsv(color)
  if s < neutro or v < neutro:
    return "Neutro"
  if limite < h < limite+rango:
    return "Frío"
  return "Cálido"
```

Algunos ejemplos:

```
colores = ["#FA5421", "#2154FA", "#20D0E3", "#E055A3",
           "#C7A887", "#79ff00", "#00ff79", "#608060"]

for i, color in enumerate(colores):
  print(i, calidez(color))
```

Como referencia, los colores analizados son los siguientes (observar la sutil y un tanto subjetiva diferencia entre los tres verdes del final):

[image: Colores de ejemplo]

Resultado:

```
0 Cálido
1 Frío
2 Frío
3 Cálido
4 Neutro
5 Cálido
6 Frío
7 Neutro
```

Answer (score 4):

El color más cálido es el rojo, cuyo código RGB es #FF0000.

El color más frío es el azul, cuyo código RGB es #00000FF.

Las dos primeras cifras indican la cantidad de rojo (Red), la tercera y la cuarta indican la cantidad de verde (Green) y las dos últimas indican la cantidad de azul (Blue). El código RGB (Red, Green, Blue) está en hexadecimal.

Para clasificar un color en cálido, frío o neutro tienes que fijarte en la parte del código RGB correspondiente al rojo y al azul.

De esta forma, si está compuesto por mucha cantidad de rojo y poca de azul, se condiera cálido. Si está compuesto por mucha cantidad de azul y poca de rojo, es frío. Si hay un equilibrio entre rojo y azul, entonces es neutro.

Para más información, puedes consultar [esta pregunta (en inglés)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615029/rgb-range-for-cold-and-warm-colors).

Para clasificar los colores en cálidos, fríos o neutros, puedes usar este código Python que he desarrollado para ti:

```
def clasificar(hex):
    if hex[0] in ("D", "E", "F") and hex[4] in ("0", "1", "2"):
        res = "El color con código RGB " + hex + " es cálido"
    elif hex[0] in ("0", "1", "2") and hex[4] in ("D", "E", "F"):
        res = "El color con código RGB " + hex + " es frío"
    else:
        res = "El color con código RGB " + hex + " es neutro"
    return res

print(clasificar("FA5421"))
print(clasificar("2154FA"))
print(clasificar("215421"))
```

El código comprueba el primer valor correspondiente al rojo y al azul. Si el valor del rojo es alto (D, E o F) y el azul bajo (0, 1 o 2), entonces el color es cálido. Si se da la situación contraria (el rojo bajo y el azul alto), es frío. En el resto de casos es un color neutro.

El resultado es:

```
El color con código RGB FA5421 es cálido
El color con código RGB 2154FA es frío
El color con código RGB 215421 es neutro
```

**Código mejorado**:

```
def clasificar(rgb):
    if not rgb.isupper():
        rgba = rgb.upper()

    if rgb[1:2] > rgb[4:5]:
        res = "El color con código RGB " + rgb + " es cálido"
    elif rgb[1:2] < rgb[4:5]:
        res = "El color con código RGB " + rgb + " es frío"
    else:
        res = "El color con código RGB " + rgb + " es neutro"
        
    return res

print(clasificar("FA5421"))
print(clasificar("2154FA"))
print(clasificar("2A542B"))
print(clasificar("0000CF"))
```

De esta forma se contemplan todos los casos y se convierte a mayúsculas la entrada de la función `clasificar(rgb)`, en caso de que haya alguna letra minúscula.

El resultado es:

```
El color con código RGB FA5421 es cálido
El color con código RGB 2154FA es frío
El color con código RGB 2A542B es cálido
El color con código RGB 0000CF es frío
```

Comment: Según tu algoritmo, `#0000CF` sería neutro, cuando es claro su componente de azul sobre el resto de colores. Si quieres comparar el canal rojo con el azul, basta con comparar cadenas: `hex[1:2] < hex[4:5]` Antes de comparar, hay que convertir la cadena `hex` a mayúsculas o minúsculas.

Comment: Gracias por la observación. He incluido un código mejorado siguiendo tus consejos.